# Animation with css that changes on click

Tags: css, css-animations

I’ m doing an animation for a website.

My client wants a row with some images.

These images have to translate constantly on load, but when I click in the row, the images must accelerate as an exponential function for 4 seconds: after that, the website must change page.

Yesterday I have created the animation, changing the animation-duration every some millis by an hook, that strategy was working perfectly, but I don’t like that because it seems to be too heavy.

Now I have found another solution that uses only css and an hook to change the class.
Given this new solution, I still have 2 issues:

1. after the click, the animation restarts
2. the second part of the animation calculates the delay from the start and not from the first part of animation

Thank you for your reply

```js
const row = document.querySelector(".row");
row.addEventListener("click", () => row.classList.add('row-click'));
```

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell{
  background:#f00;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:26px;
  min-width:100px;
  margin-right:12px;
  animation: slide-first-desktop 10s linear infinite;
}

.row-click > .cell{
  animation:
    slide-first-desktop 5s cubic-bezier(1,0,.74,1),
    slide-first-desktop 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes slide-first-desktop {
  0%{
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1680px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>
  <div class="cell">13</div>
  <div class="cell">14</div>
  <div class="cell">15</div>
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on the `animation-delay` to queue the two animations, you can listen to animation events in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationstart_event

```
const animation = document.querySelector('p.animation');

animation.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  console.log('animation started');
  animation.classList.add('animation-running');
  // do something
});

animation.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('animation ended');
  animation.classList.remove('animation-running');
  // do something
});
```

In the example, I'm using the events to toggle a `animation-running` class. You could use this to check if an animation is running and prevent to restart it on click.

Comment: thank you so much, your suggest seems work, but now I must resolve the other issue

Comment: what other issue?

Comment: when start the second animation ( on click ), the animation restart, I would like that the animation start from position when is on click

Comment: I see, I think I didn't understand that in the question, then. From what I can tell, there's no way of doing that with CSS only. I'm wondering if you could do that using CSS transitions. They normally can't be looped, but if you combine them with JavaScript, listening to transitionstart and transitionend events I think you could create a kind of loop. Otherwise, I would look into some animation libraries like Greensock

Comment: my first version combined javascript and css, but I don't like it because I think that is to heavy, then I would like use the pure css to does it

Comment: I read that, but it depends what you mean by heavy: Greensock might be "heavy" in terms of size, because you need to import a whole external library, but in terms of performances it's incredible

Comment: one last point: not sure if this is what you tried, but you could have a look at the Web Animation API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API
It relies on JavaScript, but it should allow to do what you want, for example, have a look at this: https://codepen.io/rachelnabors/pen/GZpREz