# Marquee smooth scroll doesn't display all my images. Cuts off after the first 5 images

Tags: html, css, marquee

I'm trying to make a smooth scrolling marquee that displays a few images. However, after displaying the first few images, it just cuts off and restarts. Below is a demo so you get an idea of the problem. As you can see Images 6 to 10 do not get displayed:

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 103px;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-600%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
  <span>Image 5</span>
  <span>Image 6</span>
  <span>Image 7</span>
  <span>Image 8</span>
  <span>Image 9</span>
  <span>Image 10</span>
</div>
```

EDIT: With the help of **cs1349459's** answer, I was able to display all the images from 1 to 10. However, if you check the demo code again, I am facing one more issue. After the last Image 10, it has a little jerk before displaying Image 1. I wanted to know a way that could create a smooth scroll without that jerking motion between Image 10 and 1. There shouldn't be any gap between them either.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO62832730: Animation with css that changes on click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62832730/2015909)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the spans were not moving over enough. Below is the fixed copy:

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 103px;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1000%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
  <span>Image 5</span>
  <span>Image 6</span>
  <span>Image 7</span>
  <span>Image 8</span>
  <span>Image 9</span>
  <span>Image 10</span>
</div>
```

Also be aware that there is an entire marqee element, thought I am not sure supported it is.

Here is an example of it using the marqee element:

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 103px;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<marquee>
  <span>Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
  <span>Image 5</span>
  <span>Image 6</span>
  <span>Image 7</span>
  <span>Image 8</span>
  <span>Image 9</span>
  <span>Image 10</span>
</marquee>
```

**EDIT:** To fix your new problem, just change the animation values, add another CSS statement for the `body`, and change the animation from the `span`s to the container:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 103px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(75%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Image 1</span>
  <span>Image 2</span>
  <span>Image 3</span>
  <span>Image 4</span>
  <span>Image 5</span>
  <span>Image 6</span>
  <span>Image 7</span>
  <span>Image 8</span>
  <span>Image 9</span>
  <span>Image 10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got it to display all the images from 1 to 10. However, I'm facing one other issue. I would appreciate it if you took another look at my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the whole container?
Try my example:
https://codepen.io/Nargus/pen/xxZzRpw

```
.marquee {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 103px;
}
```

Also it migth be a good improvement to use `display: inline-flex;` on .marquee

This way you won't need inline-block and nowrap